# How can I use WMI Qualifiers so that I can assign string variables to a WMI property

Tags: powershell, wmi

Can someone give me an example or point me to the direction on what Qualifier to use so that I can assign a string value to a WMI Property?

I can assign numeric value to a WMI Property but I want to assign a string value to a specific WMI Property.

I am really at lost.

here is my sample script

```
$mess = "sample output text"
$newClass = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass ("root\cimv2", [String]::Empty, $null);  
$newClass["__CLASS"] = "Sample_WMI_Class";
$newClass.Qualifiers.Add("Static", $true)
$newClass.Properties.Add("Off", [System.Management.CimType]::UInt16, $false)
$newClass.Properties["Off"].Qualifiers.Add("Static", $true)
$newClass.Properties["Off"].Qualifiers.Add("Key", $true)
newClass.Properties.Add("MachineName", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$newClass.Put()

Set-WmiInstance -Class Sample_WMI_Class -Arguments @{MachineName=$mess}
```

but I am getting this error

```
Set-WmiInstance : Illegal null value
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WmiInstance -Class Sample_WMI_Class -Arguments @{MachineName=$mes ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance
```

I just need some help to understand the error I am getting

Really need some advise or at least some examples

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a custom WMI provider of class definition or an existing/builtin one? I don't think you need any qualifiers, just specify the type of the property as `[System.Management.CimType]::String`

Comment: Yes this is a custom WMI. Sorry I forgot to mention. Thank you for replying. Will test this